# trigger the Onclick event on a tab in sugarcrm with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

I have 3 tabs in a sugarcrm ( 6.4 ) window.  If I click on a certain tab, I would like to trigger a JavaScript function. The onclick event needs to be triggered when clicking on the tab label, not when clicking inside the tab page.

Answer (score 0):

We use YUI 2 TabView, so you should be able to follow the examples in the documentation link below to handle the click event.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/tabview/#using

Comment: Can you supply an example for a tabpage label in sugar ?